# Did overturning Roe cause all pre-Roe abortion laws that were never repealed to go back into effect?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court, abortion

When *Dobbs* overruled *Roe*, did laws that were struck down under *Roe* go back into force if they were never repealed by the legislature that enacted them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is what happened when *Dobbs* was decided (ignoring the technicality of whether it was on the date of the decision or on the date that the deadline for filing and ruling on a petition for rehearing has expired).